# ExpandableListView - locating child widgets

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an `ExpandableListView` with various widgets in the child nodes. These widgets are defined in a separate layout xml file for the child nodes, which gets 'inflated' when a parent group is opened, i.e. in `BaseExpandableListAdapter.getChildView` . How can I get the view of a recently inflated child node, I need this view so that I can call `findViewById` on it and access the widgets?

From `BaseExpandableListAdapter.getChildView` this is trivial, but I need to either do it from my Main Activity (specifically, because I am calling `getSupportLoaderManager` to populate some on the widgets from a database), or else call a method of my main Activity class from `BaseExpandableListAdapter.getChildView`. In the latter case, I don't know how to access my main Activity class from `BaseExpandableListAdapter.getChildView`.